# mongodb c# returning different type depending on the collection

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a mongo database and a c# method that return the desire collection depending on the collection name.

```
public static IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> ConnectDB(string _collection)
    {
        MongoClient _client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var _db = _client.GetDatabase("cars_db");
        return _db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(_collection);
    }
```

what I want is to return a different type depending on the collection, for example, if I want the collection "car" I want the return type be IMongoCollection(Car), no BsonDocument. any ideas?

thanks,

Comment: Then you want to build a car Entity class

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer

```
public static IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> ConnectDB(string _collection)
    {
        MongoClient _client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        switch (_collection) 
        {
        case 'Car':
             var _db = _client.GetDatabase("cars_db");
             return _db.GetCollection<Car>(_collection);
           break;

        case 'Season':
           var _db = _client.GetDatabase("season_db");
           return _db.GetCollection<Season>(_collection);
           break;

        case 'client':
           var _db = _client.GetDatabase("client_db");
           return _db.GetCollection<Client>(_collection);
          break;
        }
     }
```

Comment: I already tried this. that code it's not going to work because you're declaring that the return type is going to be a BsonDocument (IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>) and the returning type in the switch isn't a BsonDocument, in this example is a Car collection, a Season collection or a Client collection.